# Defer use of bound values from custom dependency properties until control can use them

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, dependency-properties

I'm creating a custom WPF control that supplies a xaml binding syntax for manipulating Google Maps running in a browser.

When the control is constructed and the InitializeComponent() executes, the bindings provided by the user in xaml are updated. I'm looking for a best-practice recommendation (and some detail on how to) for what to do with the binding-provided values since they can't be used until Google Maps loads in the browser.

Should I keep the value in a temporary location until the page is loaded, or should I ask for all of the bound properties to update when the web page is ready?

I might prefer to trade the performance for code cleanliness if invalidating everything works correctly.

As an example:

```
private void WebControl_OnLoadingFrameComplete(object sender, FrameEventArgs e) {
    if (e.IsMainFrame) {
        googleMapPageReady = true;

        //which should I do:
        //update every method for which I have a cached value?
        if(mapCenter != null)
            SetCenter(mapCenter);


        //or this - which doesn't seem to work anyway
        this.InvalidateProperty(MapCenterProperty);
    }
}

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MapCenterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MapCenter", typeof(string), typeof(GoogleMap), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnMapCenterPropertyChanged));

    public string MapCenter {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MapCenterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MapCenterProperty, value); }
    } 

    private static void OnMapCenterPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e){
        GoogleMap control = source as GoogleMap;
        control.SetCenter(e.NewValue.ToString());
    }

    private string mapCenter;
    public void SetCenter(string latlng) {
        if (webControl == null || !googleMapPageReady) {
            mapCenter = latlng;
            return;
        }

        string[] centerPair = latlng.Split(' ');
        string center = string.Format(@"{{lat:{0}, lng:{1}}}", centerPair[0], centerPair[1]);
        webControl.ExecuteJavascript(string.Format("setCenter({0})", center));
    }
```

Comment: So, your bindings are not updated once google maps are loaded ?

Comment: I'd simply call `SetCenter(MapCenter ?? string.Empty);` and equivalently for other properties. But that's just an opinion.

Comment: That's correct, right now they updated in the constructor - and as I think through it, I want the UserControl properties to run their bindings when the control is created, but I want to update the map's values when the map loads.

Comment: It depends upon how you are using `Bindings`. Easiest way is to set `DataContext` to null, and then re-assign it.